# Matching filenames with list using a loop ignoring already "processed" files

Tags: python

What I want to do is match a set of files and sort out the ones I want (matching the extention) ignoring other I've already processed using a list

What I've come up with so far is

```
mylist = []
extensions = ['*.txt', '*.foo', '*.bar']
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    skip = None
    for ext in extensions:
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, ext):
            for test in mylist:
                if test == filename:
                    skip = True
            if not skip:
                ## do my thing
                mylist.append(filename)
```

But its ignoring my if test statement. Am I going blind?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `skip = True` but never reset `skip`, so once you skipped a filename, the rest is skipped too. Moreover, a simple `if filename not in mylist` would have sufficed, there was no need to do an explicit loop.

However, you want to use a `set` here for fast membership testing, and you can simplify your logic in any case:

```
seen = set()
extensions = ['*.txt', '*.foo', '*.bar']
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    for ext in extensions:
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, ext):
            if filename not in seen:
                # do your thing
                seen.add(filename)
```

Next, we can get rid of the `fnmatch.filter` option here, using `.endswith()` is going to be simpler and faster:

```
seen = set()
extensions = ('.txt', '.foo', '.bar')
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(extensions) and filename not in seen:
            # do your thing
            seen.add(filename)
```

The `.endswith()` can take a *tuple* of strings to look for; in this case your sequence of extensions.

If you want to only consider filenames *without* the extension, remove the extension before testing against `seen`:

```
extensions = ('.txt', '.foo', '.bar')
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(extensions):
            root, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
            if root in seen:  # we have seen this filename without extension already
                continue

            # do your thing
            seen.add(root)
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn very informative :) Im currently testing the stuff you posted, will post back soon with my findings!

Comment: Ok so after a little tinkering I end up with this, pastebin.com/TWKkRS4p It seems like it ignores the if filename.endswith as it still adds the list to the textfile and processFile() never gets executed

Comment: @JoelKåberg: I'd not use blanket `except` statements; they too easily mask other problems you want to know about. Are there more specific exceptions that you can catch instead?

Comment: @JoelKåberg: Since you read `processedFiles` in whole, you need to re-write the file, not append. Not a big problem, since you use a set when reading, but the file will contain a lot of duplicates after a few runs.

Comment: @JoelKåberg: Otherwise the code looks entirely correct to me. I'd add print statements or use `pdb` to further work out what is going on, and most of all not use blanked `except:` handlers.

Comment: Thanks (eller takk, såg at du er ifra Norge), think I'll give abit of rest for now. Still struggeling with that if statement.. Thanks for your help anyhow :)

Comment: Bare hyggelig! Not a problem.